# configure antiforgerytoken single use mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, csrf

I want to modify the AntiForgeryToken for each request.

I read these posts:

- [Is it possible to make the AntiForgeryToken value in ASP.NET MVC change after each verification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220664/is-it-possible-to-make-the-antiforgerytoken-value-in-asp-net-mvc-change-after-ea)
- [ASP.NET MVC Anti Forgery Token Insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519643/asp-net-mvc-anti-forgery-token-insecure)

The initial post clearly rules it out, but the latter seems to mention that it is "quite simple". However I did not quite get how to achieve single use for the token.

Under my current implementation I have tokens delivered as Secure http-only cookies. But it stays constant for the entire session. I don't care if my implementation breaks the back button. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have your example not sure how you are using this, but a simple form like this does display a new token on every request in the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)<fieldset>
    <legend>Person</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset> }
```

Form above shows me different values in each request like

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="53WW641jzT5QWcIrrLltqF0OGt79US1eBwue1MQU6lW200CxUiD6fcC949RZee4gcNrFNnaP5QYFi6lJd_QmuUqSfex7wWHwWjUC30_kVrI1" />
```

`<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="QXHlA8N9g_95YbPeEpjPHhjQFV9IMNJf7eEdnPnADH9BPgQg_DQQKQqf9diPAxMQWJoBcT6FeXCIECe-Qd6Q6wA5BimVlU9K0C67nokzuXQ1" />`

There is more information on [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313804/antiforgerytoken-changes-per-request%20here) which also references to other detailed information [outside here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/%20here)

Comment: Thanks, but its not what I asked specifically. I understand that a new token is generated where '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()' is called. However what I want to know is, on the server side, how do I reject a request which contains a verification token that has been previously used.

Comment: with the current implementation, there is nothing preventing the client from submitting the same form multiple times with the same antiforgery token. Its reusable. Even though a new one is generated for each page load. (or even if `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is called multiple times on the same page)